# Change where newly created RPM's are stored

Tags: linux, rhel, rpm, variable

Fairly new to creating RPM's but I have the basics down. I am working on scripting the basics and have a requirement where I cannot accept the default location for where the newly created RPM's will be stored.

Normally the RPM's that are created are stored inside of ~/rpmbuild/RPMS

I need them to be saved to /centralStorage/Some/New/Location.

What variable is the RPM builder looking for to know where to save the newly created RPM's? I cannot seem to find in the documentation how I can manaually change this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is set using the `_topdir` macro, e.g.,

```
%_topdir /home/ed/mybuild
```

You can fine tune this using dependent macros.  On a Fedora system, the macros are in `/usr/lib/rpm/macros`, including this:

```
#       The directory where newly built binary packages will be written.
%_rpmdir                %{_topdir}/RPMS
```

So you could override just `_rpmdir`.

Usually I just use settings in `$HOME/.rpmmacros`, others use command-line option `--define`, e.g.,

```
rpmbuild --define '_topdir /Location/On/Storage/' -bb myNewServer.spec
```

Further reading:

- [Having RPM Use a Different Build Area](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/s1-rpm-anywhere-different-build-area.html) (Maximum RPM: Taking the RPM Package Manager to the Limit)
- [How to pass user defined parameters to rpmbuild to fill variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21559477/how-to-pass-user-defined-parameters-to-rpmbuild-to-fill-variables)
- [Passing conditional parameters into a rpm build](http://rpm.org/api/4.4.2.2/conditionalbuilds.html) (for rpm **4**)

Comment: I ended up using the following `rpmbuild --define '_topdir /Location/On/Storage/' -bb myNewServer.spec`. I figured you may want to add that to your answer in case someone else stumbles upon this (although I believe it is inside of your link).